# display problem in UIView iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, landscape

I have a small application ipad, portrait mode is locked in the application,
The problem occurs when I turn down the IPAD, the display of the application is not running down
Can someone help me??

Comment: you mean to say when you turn to landscape mode ?

Answer (score 2):

You should implement below method in all of your viewControllers.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

Hope this help.